# Taskwarrior: Recurring tasks that are due relative to the day of recurence

Tags: utilities, taskwarrior

I would like to create a task in taskwarrior that repeats every day and is due every day or the day after. Is that possible?

Didn't find anything on the net or the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Recurrence is possible, as documented here.](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/recurrence.html) Here is the example given by the documentation:

```
task add Pay the rent due:1st recur:monthly until:2015-03-31
```

In your case, to create a task that recurs daily starting today:

```
task add Pay the rent recur:daily due:eod
```

To create a task that recurs every other day, use any of the [duration formats](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/durations.html) (we can make this one due tomorrow):

```
task add Pay the rent recur:2d due:tomorrow
```

Note that `tomorrow` will actually evaluate to `eod`, and so using something more explicit like `wednesday` (start of Wednesday) may be more appropriate. You can also, with some limitations, use durations in the due date (in this case, `due:2d`).

Note also the [limitations of recurrence in Taskwarrior](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/design/recurrence.html).