# How to manage recurring tasks in taskwarrior?

Tags: taskwarrior

I am having troubles understanding how to manage recurring tasks in [taskwarrior](https://taskwarrior.org/)

I start with an empty database:

```
$ task
[task next]
No matches.
```

I add a recurring daily task:

```
$ task add recur:daily due:later test
```

It shows up in the report:

```
$ task
[task next]

ID Age Recur Due   Description Urg 
 2 -     P1D 19.2y test         2.4

1 task
Creating recurring task instance 'test'
```

If I mark it done like this:

```
$ task 2 done
Completed task 2 'test'.
Completed 1 task.
$ task
[task next]
No matches.
```

it disappears from the report. I believe it makes sense, since "I completed the daily task today".

The problem is it never appears again the next day and further. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't use it, and so surfed the ... six... questions we have on it here at U&L and found a link to an [online doc about recurrence](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/recurrence.html) from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375372/taskwarrior-recurring-tasks-that-are-due-relative-to-the-day-of-recurence) that indicates you might have to run [task reports all](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/report.html) -- does that work? (or possibly `tasks recurring`)

Comment: The all report shows just everything, including tasks marked done and deleted ones. I am rather looking for the right way to manage recurring tasks the right way, because I've been struggling for a while and it really feels like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently recurring tasks should have the same companion **due** settings. For example:

```
$ task add "a daily recurring task" recur:daily due:eod

$ task add "a weekly recurring task" recur:weekly due:eow

$ task add "a monthly recurring task" recur:monthly due:eom
```

this way, the daily task can be marked done and won't show up again till next day

same for weekly/monthly etc tasks

Answer (score 7):

Before I dive into the working details, note that recurrence is not [well-designed](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/design/recurrence.html). What I bring is empirical observations and liable to change with a rework.

#### TLDR; How do I use and make sense of recurrence

```
task add recur:<duration> due:<first task due date> until:<delete first task by date> wait:<date when task will appear> "my task"
```

Example:

- `task add recur:daily due:9:00 until:12:00 wait:5:00 eat breakfast`
- Eat breakfast at 9:00 AM
- Hide task until 5:00 AM
- Remove task by lunch time
- Create a new occurrence everyday

#### Details

Recurrence requires a `due` attribute (enforced with a [validation check](https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskwarrior/commit/8e34a0281111000933ae2b55c27abeb036501568#diff-ed89bfc63927e96eabc804aec9363663c3bcd6a297f062eb27d7c332b58ee225R1089)).
Recurrence can also use `until` and `wait` attributes, if they exist.
Recurrence does not use `scheduled`.
And there is a `mask` attribute, that tracks which instance of the reoccurence the task is.

When a new recurring instance is created:

- `new task due` = `parent due` + `recur` * `mask`
- identical math for both `until` and `wait`
- `scheduled` is copied wholesale from the parent task. In practice, this unexpected behaviour won't break your workflow, just affects filters and skews urgency. I call this out because it took me a very long time to discover this was not working as expected.

Every time `taskwarrior` runs, it checks to see if it's time to create the next occurrence. The psuedo-equation is:

```
now >= due + recur * (mask + 1)`
```

Note, there is a config value, `rc.recurrence.limit`, that can be used to tell taskwarrior to create even more occurrences further out.

You can expect the next occurrence to be created at the due date of the previous.